# About android app development using jQuery mobile and html

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

I am a PHP programmwe and I love jQuery, javascript , css HTML most ..

I heard that we can make android apps using jQuery mobile , HTML5 ..

Can any one give me a kick starting for the same ?
I am very new to android apps development

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could start reading the documentation of JQuery mobile. http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make an Android app strictly with jQuery mobile in the sense of an `apk` file that would be available in the Android market. You can, however, make an excellent mobile web app (website) that functions like an app.

Other options for using jQuery mobile to deploy an Android app could include [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) or [Titanium](http://developer.appcelerator.com/) to name a few.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the comment and I made a page with jQuery mobile and with a simple web service. Can you advise how to convert this to an apk file . I already downloaded phonegap .. I am very new bee .. Pelase help

Comment: I think the Phonegap wiki is the best place to start with this - http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile